# PHP adding a "\"s when trying to output html

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP Code that loads some HTML from the database and `echo` to my cpage, Problem is when I `echo` code the HTML becomes like this:

```
<div class="\&quot;schema-faq-code\&quot;" itemscope="\&quot;\&quot;" itemtype="\&quot;https://schema.org/FAQPage\&quot;">
<div itemscope="\&quot;\&quot;" itemprop="\&quot;mainEntity\&quot;" itemtype="\&quot;https://schema.org/Question\&quot;" class="\&quot;faq-question\&quot;">
<h3 itemprop="\&quot;name\&quot;" class="\&quot;faq-q\&quot;">test quistion?</h3>
<div itemscope="\&quot;\&quot;" itemprop="\&quot;acceptedAnswer\&quot;" itemtype="\&quot;https://schema.org/Answer\&quot;">
<p itemprop="\&quot;text\&quot;" class="\&quot;faq-a\&quot;">Test answer</p>
</div>
</div>
```

My Code to `echo` HTML:

```
<?php
   $cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");
   if (isset($cat_data['faq'])){
      echo $cat_data['faq'];
   } } ?>
```

Comment: Seems like the issue is when you are storing the data, not outputting it. What's in the DB and how are you storing it there? Perhaps escaping, then encoding HTML special chars, then escape again, or binding?

Comment: @user3783243 I sorting data with Wodpress function like this:  `update_option( "category_$t_id", $cat_meta );`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How save JavaScript and HTML in option without it being auto-escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932018/how-save-javascript-and-html-in-option-without-it-being-auto-escaped)

Comment: If the issue is coming from `magic_quotes`. You likely need to update your PHP and/or WordPress. That is a verryyyy old function and has been removed from PHP versions from the past +4 years. See https://thephp.cc/articles/why-magic-quotes-are-gone-in-php7 for a history.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
     $cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");
     if (isset($cat_data['faq'])){
     echo html_entity_decode($cat_data['faq'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
     } } ?>
```

Comment: That wouldn't fix the backslashes, that would just decode the entities and break the full DOM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).